# Where does macOS store the desktop picture change time?

Tags: macos, desktop-wallpaper

I want to determine programmatically whether a user has enabled automatic desktop picture change in the background & screensaver preferences or not (and also the change time).

I know that recent versions of macOS store desktop picture information in the sqlite3 database `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`. But it lacks any details regarding the picture change settings.

In older versions of macOS there existed a plist file `com.apple.desktop.plist`, but it seems to be no longer in use.

Does anyone know where macOS stores this information nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

Is AppleScript an option?

```
tell application "System Events"
    set pictureRotation to picture rotation of desktops
    set changeIntervals to change interval of desktops
end tell
```

Both results are a list because you can have multiple displays.

`pictureRotation` contains the information whether the user has checked "Change Picture" (0 or 1).
`changeIntervals` contains the interval in seconds.